# React App Not able to connect with express when deployed into production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, vercel

I am building a React app with express backend.Running production and development versions both on my computer works fine but when deployed to vercel I get a 404 error

```
Request URL: https://brightigo.vercel.app/api/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404
```

Backend does not Respond to the request.

Here is my code
`server code index.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./Model/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to mongo DB '))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.use('/', express.static('dist'));

app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  // I'm not writing all the code here but it works fine in development so i don't think there is error in code
});

app.post('/api/createUser', async (req, res) => {});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 8080}!`);
});
```

webpack.common.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 100000 } }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'public/Images/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
    }),
    new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[contentHash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
});
```

webpack.dev.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const outputDirectory = 'dist';

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
  },
  // debug: true,
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: false,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8080',
    },
  },
});
```

```
//package.json
  "description": "React App",
  "main": "src/server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "npm run build && node src/server/index.js",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "server": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

Link for github repo if you want to know more [link](https://github.com/demonicirfan/brightigo)

Comment: I think something is wrong with your redirects. Your page loads correctly on https://brightigo.vercel.app because it probably redirects to the correct page (could be on another url) but if you reload the page you get a 404 too. Can you check your domain/redirect settings?

Comment: Also small type: `'bundle.[contentHash].js'` should be `'bundle.[contenthash].js'` -> [Webpack output](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/under-the-hood/#output)